# How to do Multiclass classification with Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I want to make simple classifier with Keras that will classify my data. Features are numeric data and results are string/categorical data. I'm predicting 15 different categories/classes. This is how my code looks:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, input_dim = x_train.shape[1], activation = 'relu')) # input layer requires input_dim param
model.add(Dense(16, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer= "adam", metrics=['accuracy'])

#es = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', min_delta=0.005, patience=1, verbose=1, mode='auto')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 100, shuffle = True, batch_size=128, verbose=2)

scores = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print(model.metrics_names[0], model.metrics_names[1])
```

the problem is that I'm always getting this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float 'category1'
```

What am I doing wrong?

When I replace my classes names "category1", "category2" etc with integer numbers, my code works but it always give me accuracy of 0.
I have tried to change number of nodes and layers and activation functions  but the result is always 0. It seams like the model thinks that I'm doing regression not classification.

What is the correct way to do classification with Keras lib If my categorical values are not just 1 or 0?

Comment: You don't have the right activation, for binary classification you want sigmoid at the output layer, not ReLU. Then it will work.

Comment: I have tried that, but. also, same error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to convert your string categories to integers, there is a method for that:

```
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=num_classes)
```

Also, the last layer for multi-class classification should be something like:

```
model.add(Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax'))
```

And finally, for multi-class classification, the correct loss would be categorial cross-entropy.

```
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer= "adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This is a nice example available from tensorflow: [Classification Example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification)

Comment: Thanks! 
Is there a way to increase accuracy and to reduce val_Loss?

Comment: You can play with the layers, add more neurons, increase or reduce the number of layers. If you notice that the accuracy is good on training but decreases significatively on the test set you can add a Dropout layer or look into regularization. That can help make the model more robust.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 15 classes, represented by labels 0 to 14, you can set up your final dense layer with 15 neurons and activation sigmoid `Dense(15, ...)`.

Additionaly, if you do not one-hot encode your data, set `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as loss and `sparse_categorical_accuracy` as metric.

Comment: One should not use activation sigmoid for classifying 15 (i.e more than 2) classes